# Upper bound or maximization for $xf(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, optimization

Suppose a random variable $x$, with density function $f$ (continuous and differentiable). $f$ is unimodal and symmetric around zero. Under what conditions can I show that $xf(x)$ does not exceed $1$ for $x>0$? I tried the normal distribution and it was clearly satisfied. But I wonder whether there is a more general condition for $f$.

Thanks.

Comment: Using integration by parts may help, with one of the terms $xf(x)$.

Comment: @AnyAD Could you elaborate a bit more? because I don't see how integration helps.

Comment: See the working in the answer.

Comment: How do you 'see' that this is clearly satisfied for the Normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

For $b>0$, $1/2>bf(b)-\int_{0}^b{xf'(x)dx}$. 
If the distribution $f(x)$ has only one 'peak', and is symmetric around zero, then this peak occurs at zero. So then we can assume that $f'$ is negative, so the integral part of the inequality is negative and so
\begin{equation}1/2>bf(b)+K,\end{equation} for some positive $K$.